# How to remove Android EditText cursor indicator?

Tags: android, cursor, android-edittext

When I add a multi line EditText on a view,

there is a cursor indicator below the cursor looking like a blue & large slider bar
to help user find cursor position.

It seems appear on multi-line EditText only on a touch.

I want to remove this indicator from my EditText,
to make the EditText to have one simple and thin bar cursor.

Please see the blue cursor indicator below and advise me.
Thank you.

http://liuzhichao.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/20120602133745.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:cursorVisible="false"`

OR

There is Java function available too for the same: `setCursorVisible(false)`

Comment: Thanks but I just want to remove the blue indicator below the cursor, not the cursor itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use empty image for the following property of edittext.

```
 android:textSelectHandle="@drawable/empty_button"
```